# I want to convert my File into a bitmap but it's returning null. I have tried many other ways but still stuck into it

Tags: java, android, file, kotlin, bitmap

This is my code inside onActivityResult. PathUtil class is getting full file path from Uri. I am picking single picture from Gallery :)

```
try {
    selectedFilePath = PathUtil.getPath(SmoothPhotoActivity.this, selectedImageUri);
    File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File image = new File(selectedFilePath);
    String filePath = image.getPath();
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
    Bitmap outputImage = imageFilter.processFilter(bitmap);
    ivPhotoSelected.setImageBitmap(outputImage);
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: "PathUtil class is getting full file path from Uri" -- that is not possible for the vast majority of possible `Uri` values. Ideally, use an image-loading library, like Glide or Picasso. Worst-case, use `openInputStream()` on `ContentResolver`, and pass that `InputStream` to `BitmapFactory.decodeStream()` (all on a background thread).

Comment: I have got the file path using PathUtil. The problem is now converting into a bitmap and then applying color filter to it and then show the filtered bitmap on image view. Glide is loading the Uri and that path but it's not loading the filtered bitmap because it's null.

Comment: Can you please elaborate it to me properly?

Comment: Thank you sir. I now understood and it's working fine :)